# What is an "annihilated vector"?

Tags: vectors, terminology, definition

What is the meaning of an anihilated vector?

I have seen this term in the theory of Lie group representations, precisely in Dixmier´s book, *Enveloping Algebras*. I tried to google, but only found annihilation related to physics.

Comment: Well, where did you see it?

Comment: Typically, a vector $v$ annihilated by some linear operator $T$ is taken to mean a vector in the kernel of $T$, i.e., $Tv = 0$.

Comment: In the above case we also sometimes call $T$ an "annihilator" of $v$.